# Geometric Reference(s) for finite groups of Lie type

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, lie-groups, finite-fields

Can someone please recommend some references (books, articles, lecture notes) on finite groups of Lie type, which take on a geometric approach (group actions, orbits, analogue of the Lie theory and structure theory of Lie groups). I have many questions about them, but I guess I will start by reading a little about them, before formulating any questions.

My background consists of differential geometry, some algebraic geometry, and can be summarized as "some experience over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$", but not over other fields.

Comment: So what would a finite differentiable manifold look like?

Comment: It is not what I meant. There are analogies. Using the Chevalley-Serre relations, I think one can define classical groups over the integers I think.

Comment: Do you consider sheaf theory to be geometric ? If yes this might be of interest : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deligne%E2%80%93Lusztig_theory

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet, I consider sheaves and schemes to be geometric "enough" :). I mean, the proofs are usually algebraic, but the intuition is geometric. Thank you for the link!

Comment: Meinolf Geck has a book called "An introduction to Algebraic Geometry and Algebraic Groups" that culminates in a chapter on finite groups of Lie type. Its a very self-contained elementary book and I like it a lot, although I never got to the last chapter. Most of the other chapters are probably skippable for someone who knows some AG.  I suspect the the treatment is more elementary than what you're looking for though

Comment: @Tim kinsella, thank you! I appreciate nice elementary books. It may be a good place to start!